# In Blade Runner why is Earth in such decay vs Offworlds that are (apparently) much better?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner, blade-runner-2049

In *Blade Runner* and *Blade Runner 2049* some of the primary uses of replicants are for offworld colonies. Any explanation on the situation of Earth vs Offworlds?

Comment: Also, clarify the question to be more concise if you could--e.g. A, B, and C can be asked as one question.

Comment: C: Earth was destroyed by World War Terminus. The colonies haven't (yet) had a devastating nuclear war.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot & wculen, Fixed. NicolaTalbot, Cheers, please put full answer as an answer. Because in the movies the reason why Earth is so terrible but Offworlds better, it's not clearly given.

Comment: Significant differences between novel and film in regards to this with the novel being clearer (WW Terminus, environmental and genetic collapse, etc). Kipple can stand as symbolic of this. In the Scott film it is purposely left open. There are more hints in the Fancher & Peoples script (e.g clearer statements of what the blimps are advertising noting you can go off-world "If you meet health and experience qualifications for the Offworld Emmigration Programs" (1981 script). This is likely due to the growth of cyberpunk's dystopias between Dick's novel and Scott's film. Mead talks of this, too.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143906/are-the-off-world-colonies-really-a-golden-land-of-opportunity

Comment: @Möoz I think that does seem to answer this question.

Comment: @Möoz Thanks, that QA is closest to what I'm looking for. If anyone can expand more on that QA that would be great.